# NoMethodError (undefined method `route=' for #<ActiveRecord:0x00007febf2e806f8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need some help here. I have a community model with belongs to an account. I use devise for the authentication stuff. Now the issue is when I try to submit/create a community I get this error 'undefined method `account_id=' for #Community:0x00007febf2e806f8 Did you mean? account='

controller

```
    def create
        @community = Community.new comunity_values
        @community.account_id = current_account.id

        if @community.save
            redirect_to community_path
        else 
            render :new
        end
    end
    
    private
    def comunity_values
        params.require(:community).permit(:name, :url,:rules)
    end
end
```

model

```
class Community <ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account
    validates_presence_of :url, :name , :rules
end
```

migrations

```
class CreateCommunities < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :communities do |t|
      t.references :account
      t.string :name
      t.string :url
      t.text :rules
      t.string :total_members
      t.timestamps
      
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't make any sense to me. Your code should work fine. Perhaps you edited the migration *after running it*, which is why your `communities` table doesn't have the `account_id` column? What does your database schema (`./db/schema.rb`) say? You could try `rake db:rollback` and `rake db:migrate` to re-create the table with all the correct columns? In general, if you want to edit a table after creating it then you should do that with a new database migration, not by editing the old one.

Comment: Also, you may wish to revise your question title. Not only is it inconsistent with the contents of your question, but that's a useless title for anyone googling a similar problem in the future. Perhaps something like "Undefined method for foreign key on model, added as a table reference"?

Answer (score 1):

In model account you have to put the reference to communities model too. Something like:

```
has_many :community
```

Other think you have to know, is that you don't need to specify the id when you create using relations, you could use in a more readable way:

```
@community.account = current_account

@community.save
```

And I think that you are inverting the order of things, because one account has many communities so... You could do that as follows:

```
current_account.community.create!(comunity_values)
```

Hope this helps